# How I can understand when FirstOrDefault found nothing in sorted list?

Tags: c#

I have `SortedList<DateTime, object>`. Each times in it is a `KeyValuePair<>` which is a struct. So, how can I understand when method `FirstOrDefault` found nothing in this list ?(for classes it returns `null` but for a `struct`?)

Why I just cant compare `default(KeyValuePair<Key, Value>)` and result of `FirstOrDefault`?

```
private SortedList<DateTime, GatewayPassage> gwPassages = 
    new SortedList<DateTime, GatewayPassage>(new DescDateTimeComparer());

var lastGwPassages = gwPassages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Tag == tag &&
                                                    x.Value.Gateway == gateway);
```

I want condition like "if found nothing"

```
if(lastGwPassages == %some kind of default value%)
```

Comment: Why do you want to use FirstOfDefault if you want to control finding result?

Comment: I think you should compare with `default(KeyValuePair<T,U>)` instead

Comment: You could compare if the `.Key == default(DateTime)`

Comment: Can you provide some code to make sure we're understanding your question correctly?

Comment: Please provide more actual code. Is the `default` value a value that can occur in the actual data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the items into a `KeyValuePair<DateTime,object>?` and then you will be able to check if it is equals to null.

```
SortedList<DateTime, object> collection = new SortedList<DateTime, object>()
{
    {  new DateTime(2016,1,2), new object() },
    {  new DateTime(2016,1,1), new object() },
    {  new DateTime(2016,1,3), new object() },
};

var firstOrDefault = collection.Cast<KeyValuePair<DateTime,object>?>().FirstOrDefault(); // date of 1/1/2016
var checkIfDefault = firstOrDefault == null; // false

collection.Clear();

firstOrDefault = collection.Cast<KeyValuePair<DateTime, object>?>().FirstOrDefault(); // null
checkIfDefault = firstOrDefault == null; // true
```

---

In your example code:

```
var lastGwPassages = gwPassages.Cast<KeyValuePair<DateTime,GatewayPassage>?>()
                               .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Tag == tag &&
                                                    x.Value.Gateway == gateway);
```

Now you can do `lastGwPassages == null`